# apache mod_rewrite mod_proxy subdomain to dir

Tags: linux, apache, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

i have a domain www.example.com as front end, and i have many servers having front end servers
like games.example.com
what i want www.example.com in the background will access games.example.com

so games.example.com = www.example.com/games

this code will handle any access to directory /games will access the backend server

```
<Location  /games>
ProxyPassReverse games.example.com
ProxyPassReverse games.example.com:80
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule games(.*)$ http://games.example.com/$1 [QSA,P,L]
</Location>
```

it's working but 
its giving me this url
www.example.com/web/login.php which will raise 404 page not found how can i append word games in any URL by being like this www.example.com/games/web/login.php ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Location  /games>
ProxyPassReverse games.example.com
ProxyPassReverse games.example.com:80
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule games(.*)$ http://games.example.com/games/$1 [QSA,P,L]
</Location>
```

Comment: this is wont work because games.example.com/games/ doesnt exist, what i want www.example.com/games/signup/ == games.example.com/signup/
the same issue if i have diffrent directories in the same of the subdomain to the root domain